# Error sintáctico al iterar una columna de una tabla de pandas nombrada con dos palabras

Tags: python, pandas, sintaxis

Estoy generando un set de datos como para hacer un estudio de salud, he creado un array por columna con numpy y después un data frame con pandas para hacer la tabla. 
[image: tabla]

Después modifico algunos valores de la columna Blood cholesterol pero obtengo un error sintáctico.

[image: error]
Parece ser por el espacio en blanco entre blood y cholesterol porque si lo reemplazo por un guión bajo al darle nombre a la columna, el error no aparece. Intenté usar comillas en el `if` statement y nada, el scape character tampoco funcionó, ¿alguien sabe qué es lo que pasa y si hay otra forma de solucionarlo dejando el espacio en blanco?

Comment: Si, usa `row["Blood cholesterol"]`. Y en futuras preguntas por favor no pegues el código en forma de imágenes, pues nos hace imposible copiar y pegar ese código para poder experimentar con él y ayudarte (en este caso no fue necesario, pero otras veces puede ser la única forma de descubrir el error)

Comment: Okay, muchas gracias por los dos consejos